# Add "noindex" in a link to a pdf

Tags: php, html, mpdf

I have a website where I have links to a `php script` where I generate a pdf with the [mPdf](https://mpdf.github.io/) library and it is displayed in the browser or downloaded, depending on the configuration.

The problem is that I do not want it to be indexed in `google`. I've already put the link `rel="nofollow"` with that is no longer indexed, but how can I dexindexe what are already there?

With `rel="noindex, nofollow"` does not work.

Would have to do it only by `php` or some `html` tag

Comment: This has the best answer: https://www.holadevs.com/pregunta/64514/add-noindex-in-a-link-to-a-pdf

Answer (score 3):

How Google is supposed to deindex something if you did prevent its robot from accessing the resource? ;) This may seem counter-intuitive at first.

Remove the `rel="nofollow"` on links, and in the script which is serving the PDF files, include a `X-Robots-Tag: none` header. Google will be able to enter the resource, and it will see that it is forbidden to index this particular resource and will remove the record from the index.

When deindexing is done, add the `Disallow` rule to the `robots.txt` file as @mtr.web mentions so robots won't drain your server anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a [robots.txt](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062596) file, you can stop google from indexing any particular file by adding a rule to it.  In your case, it would be something like this:

```
User-agent: *
disallow: /path/to/PdfIdontWantIndexed.pdf
```

From there, all you have to do is make sure that you [submit your robots.txt to Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6078399), and it should stop indexing it shortly thereafter.

**Note:**

It may also be wise to [remove your url from the existing Google index](https://www.sistrix.com/ask-sistrix/google-index-google-bot-crawler/how-can-i-remove-a-url-on-my-website-from-the-google-index/#Option_2_Use_the_Google_Search_Console) because this will be quicker in the case that it has already been crawled by Google.

Answer (score 1):

**Easiest way:** Add `robots.txt` to root, and add this:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /*.pdf$
```

Note: if there are parameters appended to the URL (like `../doc.pdf?ref=foo`) then this wildcard will not prevent crawling since the URL no longer ends with “.pdf”